# module.exports to export default: how to rewrite in a proper way?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on some node application and want all the code to meet ES6+ standards.

Therefore I'm trying to get rid of module.exports and replace it with export default.

How can I rewrite the following code to make it work?

```
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { secretOrKey } from './keys';

const User = mongoose.model('users');
const opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = secretOrKey;

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new Strategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { secretOrKey } from './keys';

const User = mongoose.model('users');
const opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = secretOrKey;

const someFunc = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new Strategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};

export default someFunc;
```

Comment: Thanks! That turned out pretty easy)

Comment: No worries, glad to help. You can click and accept my answer :)

Comment: Sure) For some stackoverflow logic I couldn't accept it at once, only after some time.